# How to return all dictionary values and keys from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

need some help..

I have data like:

data dict:

```
{'folder_id': 13, 'type': 'local', 'read': False, 'last_modification_date': 1653588426, 
'creation_date': 1653408009, 'status': 'completed', 'uuid': 'ebaacb26-654b-04de-b5b3- 
 337b5bb66eea9e74cdc5db8168c5', 'shared': False, 'user_permissions': 128, 'owner': 
'email@com.com', 'timezone': 'Europe/Brusel', 'rrules': 'FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU', 
'starttime': '20220211T190000', 'enabled': True, 'control': True, 'live_results': 0, 'name': 
 '6666-Test-VM01', 'id': 286}

{'folder_id': 2, 'type': 'local', 'read': True, 'last_modification_date': 1653587386, 
'creation_date': 1653399006, 'status': 'completed', 'uuid': 'fbbfbca1-ba55-31cf-7de9- 
984ab3aa2ce13223a2ed8c1b45a7', 'shared': False, 'user_permissions': 128, 'owner': 
'info@test.com', 'timezone': 'Europe/Brusel', 'rrules': 'FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU', 
'starttime': '20220215T163000', 'enabled': True, 'control': True, 'live_results': 0, 'name': 
'testvm-3', 'id': 83}

{'folder_id': 2, 'type': 'local', 'read': False, 'last_modification_date': 1653587306, 
 'creation_date': 1653348635, 'status': 'completed', 'uuid': '762ba2a8-9e73-957c-4934- 
 ae919c7148453dbdd9ea1e07b423', 'shared': False, 'user_permissions': 128, 'owner': 
'kitty@xelo.lt', 'timezone': 'Europe/Brusel', 'rrules': 'FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU', 
 'starttime': '20220209T023000', 'enabled': True, 'control': True, 'live_results': 0, 'name': 
 '111-Vm3000test', 'id': 264}
```

I'm trying to return  dictionary with all data inside, but it's returning only first or last value, how to get all data from this dictionary, my code:

```
class Testclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.resources = {}
    
    def get_data(self):
        for data in data_dict:
            self.resources['folder_id'] = data['folder_id']
            self.resources['name'] = data['name']
        return self.resources
```

output of this code:

```
{'folders_id': 13, 'name': '6666-Test-VM01'}
```

why i didint get all anothers?

Expected output:

```
{'folders_id': 13, 'name': '6666-Test-VM01'} 
{'folders_id': 2, 'name': 'testvm-3'} 
{'folders_id': 2, 'name': '111-Vm3000test'}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: {'folders_id': 13, 'folder_name': '6666-Test-VM01'}
{'folders_id': 2, 'folder_name': 'testvm-3'}
{'folders_id': 2, 'folder_name': '111-Vm3000test'}

Comment: The dict values are being overwritten with each iteration.  A dict key can only occur once; *perhaps you want a list of dicts.*

Comment: Do a bit of research on appending dicts to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data_dict` is a *list* of dictionaries, let's do the same for `resources`, you can do something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.resources = []

def get_data(self):
    for data in data_dict:
        new_dict = {}
        new_dict['folder_id'] = data['folder_id']
        new_dict['name'] = data['name']
        self.resources.append(new_dict)
    return self.resources
```

Comment: Lol, ty dude, i feel stupid now..

Comment: happens, that's how one learns! glad to help.